# Get index of the element I clicked on relative to the jquery collection

Tags: javascript, jquery, click

I have a fiddle here, very simple one.

http://jsfiddle.net/tnQne/

The js I have is here

```
$('section a').on('click', function() {
    alert($(this).index());
});
```

It always returns 0 since within section there is only 1 anchor tag. What I wanted was it returns the position of the clicked element in the jquery collection. So if I clicked on the last section anchor, it would return 2 (0 based)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to store the original collection and call [`index`](http://api.jquery.com/index) on that collection.

```
var links = $('section a').on('click', function() {
    alert(links.index(this));
});
```

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tnQne/1/)

---

The problem with your code is that `$(this).index()` will get the index of the element relative to its siblings. Since the `a` elements don't have any siblings, the index is always `0`. The API page I've linked explains how `index` function works if a DOM element is the argument.

Comment: Interesting, this works great. I didn't think storing it made a difference, apparently it does! Thanks

Comment: yes of course, calling index() on $(this) is kind of stupid now I that I see it haha

Answer (score 2):

lonesomeday has a good way to do it but another way is:

```
$('section a').on('click', function(e) {
    alert( $.inArray(e.target, $('section a')) );
});​
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/tnQne/2/)**